# How to minimize a multivariable function using scipy

Tags: python

So I have the function

```
    f(x) = I_0(exp(Q*x/nKT)
```

Where Q, K and T are constants, for the sake of clarity I'll add the values

```
Q = 1.6x10^(-19)  
K = 1.38x10^(-23)  
T = 77.6
```

and n and I_0 are the two constraints that I'm trying to minimize.

my xdata is a list of 50 datapoints and as is my ydata. So as of yet this is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
import scipy.optimize as optimize
import numpy


xdata = numpy.array([1.07,1.07994,1.08752,1.09355,
1.09929,1.10536,1.10819,1.11321,
1.11692,1.12099,1.12435,1.12814,
1.13181,1.13594,1.1382,1.14147,
1.14443,1.14752,1.15023,1.15231,
1.15514,1.15763,1.15985,1.16291,1.16482])

ydata = [0.00205,
0.004136,0.006252,0.008252,0.010401,
0.012907,0.014162,0.016498,0.018328,
0.020426,0.022234,0.024363,0.026509,
0.029024,0.030457,0.032593,0.034576,
0.036725,0.038703,0.040223,0.042352,
0.044289,0.046043,0.048549,0.050146]

#data and ydata is experimental data, xdata is voltage and ydata is current

def f(x,I0,N):
# I0 = 7.85E-07
# N = 3.185413895
    Q = 1.66E-19
    K = 1.38065E-23
    T = 77.3692
    return I0*(numpy.e**((Q*x)/(N*K*T))-1)

result = optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata,ydata) #trying to minize I0 and N
```

But the answer doesn't give suitably optimized constraints

Any help would be hugely appreciated I realize there may be something obvious I am missing, I just can't see what it is!

Comment: Can you linearise it (take a log of both sides) and fit it with linear regression (polyfit to order 1 in scipy I think)? Whether that's strictly valid depends on how the errors change across the measurements, but it's quick and easy.

Comment: yes the data is not linear, i plotted log(y) against x and it was curved, but as of yet this is the best model that I have and to get a better one I would first need to find the best values of I0 and n. I understand this leaves room for ambiguity since the model does not strictly fit the data but I thought that I could still get a min value for I0 and n even if the data and model don't perfectly match?

Comment: If log(y) against x is curved, you won't be able to fit the model to that function however you do it! I don't think the fit you're doing will give a significantly different answer to the fit I suggested. However, to try to answer your actual question a little, there's a spurious -1 in the return line of your function f. Removing that might help.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this, but for some reason if you throw out those constants so function becomes

```
def f(x,I0,N):
   return I0*(numpy.exp(x/N)-1)
```

you get something reasonable.

```
1.86901114e-13,   4.41838309e-02
```

Answer (score 0):

Its true, that when we get rid off constants its better. Define function  as:

```
def f(x,A,B):
    return A*(np.e**(B*x)-1)
```

and fit it by curve_fit, you'll be able to get A that is explicitly I0 (A=I0) and B (you can obtain N simply by N=Q/(B*K*T) ). I managed to get pretty good fit.

I think if there is too much constants, algorithm gets confused some way.

Comment: Reason I think is that min square works by solving system of linear equations and those have typical stopping conditions in range 1e-6. For solving original problem conditions are much lower.

Comment: Maybe this is the reason. Optimization algorithms usually are not perfect.